# How to serve DASH video (MPEG-DASH and HLS) over a web sever

Tags: apache, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash

I am doing a small research project to test DASH streaming on very low bandwidth mobile connections in India.

I have an AWS machine where I can upload video and package it for MPEG-DASH and HLS streaming and create the MPD and m3u8 files.

But I am unable to serve the video.

I have tried with Apache and node.js. I was told that by just placing the folder that contains the mpd nad m3u8 files with the video chunks I should be able to stream the video.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Is there any special configuration I need to do to server MPEG-DASH video ? If there a tutorial/blog/github project someone could point me towards, that would be brilliant.

TIA.

Comment: There should be no special configuration. Can you access the different files with a simple HTTP request? Maybe you could post some error log from your Apache server?

Answer (score 2):

Setting up a DASH Media streaming, is fairly involved. You can get all paid services from Bitmovin, Wowza and many others but don't give up yet. There are a lot of open-source stuff out there as well that works. I have been working on DASH for a while now.

Here's my setup,

OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Server: Apache2 (easy to setup): Few edits I had to do: CORS and an alias setting.
Client: Dash.js: Literally just get the dash.js-master branch from github. Don't get stuck with the dash.js-development branch, if you don't wanna end up editing stuff.
Content Generation: ffmpeg and MP4Box

All you have to do for initial setup is make 2 directories in your apache's root directory, (i.e. inside the folder that contains index.html). Your first directory will be the compiled dash.js client and the second will be your content directory.

Point a link on your server to the dash.js reference client, then all you have to do is play your mpd on the client. (Make sure it confirms to the mpd validation norms though)

Now, this might just work only on a computer and not a cell phone, but hey I think you disable all the connections (wireless and wired) on your computer and use one of those wireless dongles provided by Airtel/Reliance/any network provider!

Shall be here to answer more insightful questions, hath need be!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any server side application. If you are using AWS a simple S3 bucket behind Cloudfront will do the trick nicely, without any EC2 needed at all. Just ensure you have CORS and crossdomain.xml in place.

[Stefen Lederer](https://bitmovin.com/tutorials/mpeg-dash-hls-adaptive-streaming-aws-s3-cloudfront/) posted a blog about just this set up.

Also, use your browsers developer mode to catch failed requests and console errors which might give pointers as to why it is not working for you.